# Reading GeoPackages with GeoPandas throws error: UnsupportedGeometryTypeError: 15

Tags: geopandas, geopackage

I try to read GeoPackages with GeoPandas and get the following error as shown in my Jupyter notebook:

```
File ~\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\with_qgis_jptr\Lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py:259, in _read_file(filename, bbox, mask, rows, engine, **kwargs)
    256     path_or_bytes = filename
    258 if engine == "fiona":
--> 259     return _read_file_fiona(
    260         path_or_bytes, from_bytes, bbox=bbox, mask=mask, rows=rows, **kwargs
    261     )
    262 elif engine == "pyogrio":
    263     return _read_file_pyogrio(
    264         path_or_bytes, bbox=bbox, mask=mask, rows=rows, **kwargs
    265     )

File ~\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\with_qgis_jptr\Lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py:351, in _read_file_fiona(path_or_bytes, from_bytes, bbox, mask, rows, where, **kwargs)
    349     f_filt = features
    350 # get list of columns
--> 351 columns = list(features.schema["properties"])
    352 datetime_fields = [
    353     k for (k, v) in features.schema["properties"].items() if v == "datetime"
    354 ]
    355 if kwargs.get("ignore_geometry", False):

File ~\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\with_qgis_jptr\Lib\site-packages\fiona\collection.py:293, in Collection.schema(self)
    286 """Returns a mapping describing the data schema.
    287 
    288 The mapping has 'geometry' and 'properties' items. The former is a
    289 string such as 'Point' and the latter is an ordered mapping that
    290 follows the order of fields in the data file.
    291 """
    292 if not self._schema and self.mode in ("a", "r") and self.session:
--> 293     self._schema = self.session.get_schema()
    294 return self._schema

File fiona\ogrext.pyx:828, in fiona.ogrext.Session.get_schema()

File fiona\_geometry.pyx:54, in fiona._geometry.normalize_geometry_type_code()

UnsupportedGeometryTypeError: 15
```

The GeoPackages are a result from using the ogr2ogr-tool to convert gml-data to geopackages and can be imported to QGIS without any errors.

What may be the problem (and how I could fix it)?

Comment: Fiona supports these geometry types https://fiona.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#geometry-types. Obviously your GML data contains also something else, like non-linear geometries.

Comment: You can check what geometrytypes there are in the gpkg table for example with ogrinfo `ogrinfo -sql "select distinct geometrytype(geom) from my_table" my_geopackage.gpkg`. Use the real name of the geometry column instead of "geom".

Comment: Geometry type 15 is PolyhedralSurface ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry#:~:text=3014-,PolyhedralSurface,-0015)). Is this what you expect?

Comment: Yes, thank you all very much. It is correct, that I have PolyhedralSurfaces.

Comment: You could try if using "pyogrio" engine to read the file helps by specifying `engine="pyogrio"` in your `geopandas.read_file()` call... If that doesn't help, would it be possible to provide a test file?